# How to load a jar file in my program vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, classpath, project, derby

Hello Stackoverflow.
       I cannot use these .jar files in my code...I need those files to manage a local database managed by derby.

I tried to add the lib folder to the classpath, but it didn't work.

When I try to '''org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver''' it does not find it.
I use VSCode as my main editor. I cannot change VSCode, but for the future, I will consider other options.
I leave this screenshot here regarding my folder structure.
[image]

Comment: Are you getting a `DRIVER DROOOOOP` when you run the application? Which plugins are you using to manage the java project in VS Code?

Comment: I am getting DRIVER DOOP, I do not use any kind of plugins. I created the java project by clicking on 'create java project', and it created this folder structure.

Comment: Now I managed to add .jar files to my classpath so that I can write the ''' import org.apache.derby.* '''. The question is why Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); does not work? I used this lines to the .classpath to get the .jar files to work <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib./derby.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib./derbyclient.jar"/>

Comment: What exception is printed by the line 42 call to `printStackTrace`?

Comment: Looks like I managed after all to make it work. I went to the .classpath file from the project, and added the jar files individualy, with the kind set to lib. The bad thing is that i had to add them individualy, i can’t add a folder

Comment: try adding your jars in the .classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to define the path like this in your `.classpath` file :

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/derby.jar"/> 
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/derbyclient.jar"/>
```

refer to [add jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_adding-external-jar)

Comment: Yes, this works, but I have to do it for every file individualy, isn’t there an easier version so i can add a whole folder?